# Rename Directory And Replace Only Updated Files Unix/Linux Command Line

Tags: linux, mv

I have a nightly backup that creates a new folder each night and saves a copy of each of the files in the directories selected. What I would like to have happen is once the backup folder is created example: `backup 2017-01-07` and is complete I run a shell script to check the files in the new backup and replace only the files that have been updated in a folder example: `daily_backup`.

I have looked at the mv command which does not seem to provide exactly what I am looking for based on the articles and blogs I have read. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "replace only the files that have been updated"? You're checking the freshly created backup; nothing should have been updated in there.

Comment: Im not really sure but maybe rsync is what you want

Comment: `backup 2017-01-07` Don't put spaces in file or directory names!

Comment: @RedCricket Why not?

Comment: Because it adds complexity to anyone that may have to maintain the system. I am surprised that someone with over 20K in reputation would need to ask that question.

Comment: So the issue is the backup is automatically created with the date at the end. I want the files from the new backup folder (the one with the date) to replace any files in the daily_backup folder that the updated timestamp is newer . I don't have access to the backup software and the backup software doesn't seem to have the ability to only update files that have been changed since the last update.

Comment: lucianopaz suggestion of using rsync will probably work for you.

Comment: Looking at rsync it appears that is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks lucianopaz and Red Cricket.

Comment: @RedCricket How does it add complexity?

Comment: I guess you could search SO for "how to deal with spaces in shell script" but  I did that for you. Take look here and you may want to move your comments to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script/256225#256225